# 3rd level and SKU sorting issues, need your advise

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm working on a store right now with 3 level of categories. We've set the 1st level category (mother category) on the left sidebar to display categories as a simple list, once a customer will click on the first level the 2nd level and 3rd level will display but the speed of the site is now very slow as we used API to implement these changes. Is there any way we can make the site load faster?

I'd like to sort my product using the SKU when it display on the product pages. Any advise on how I can arrange the products or sort the products based on the SKU?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Armand! While I'm not a web expert, those that are will be able to help you if you're more specific and give more context. E.g., what API you're using? Are you using specific web technologies or languages? (If so, add them to your tags.) How slow is the site loading, and what web server / host are you using? (Also, it would be good to limit future questions to a single theme: right now, you have two themes -- one relating to sorting, and one relating to speed -- which is less common here and thus more likely to be passed over.) Good luck getting an answer, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @DylanKnowles They are using the BigCommerce API as seen here: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api -- unsure of technology stack. It would be ideal to not make these API calls from the storefront if that is the case. It would be better to use something like heroku to have more complex logic that can be cached and sent to the storefront.